# How to solve equations of the form $(a+x)^2 + (b+x)^2 +(c+x)^2 + (d+x)^2-e=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation of the form $(a+x)^2 + (b+x)^2 +(c+x)^2 + (d+x)^2-e=0$ where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ are known.

My question is how would I derive $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**: Use $(a+x)^2 = a^2+2ax+x^2$, and similarly expand the other $3$ squares, then combine like terms and rewrite it in the form $Ax^2+Bx + C = 0$ and use a quadratic formula !

Comment: Of course. For a moment I couldn't see the wood for the trees :-)  Thank you for bringing that moment of clarity into my life.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:**

$(a+x)^2+(b+x)^2+(c+x)^2+(d+x)^2-e=0\implies$

$\color{red}{4}x^2+\color{green}{2(a+b+c+d)}x+\color{blue}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-e}=0\implies$

$x_{1,2}=\frac{-\color{green}{2(a+b+c+d)}\pm\sqrt{(\color{green}{2(a+b+c+d)})^2-4\cdot\color{red}{4}\cdot(\color{blue}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-e})}}{2\cdot\color{red}{4}}$

Comment: The linear term is not $2abcd \cdot x$, it's $2(a+b+c+d) \cdot x$

Comment: @MichaelCromer: Yeah I just noticed that... Will fix; thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Let us make it more general for the expression $$A=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+x)^2$$ Expanding each square and grouping terms, we have $$A=n x^2+2\Big(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\Big)x+\Big(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\Big)$$ Defining $S_1=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$, $S_2=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$, then the roots of the equation $A=B$ are given by $$x_{\pm}=\frac{-S_1\pm \sqrt{S_1^2-n(S_2-B)}}{n}$$